# Typechecker assertion failed on recursively-typed class

Tags: recursion, polymorphism, ocaml, assertion, typechecking

Consider the following small example:

```
type 'r foo_t = <get : 'r bar option ; set : 'r bar option -> 'r; ..> as 'r 

and 'r bar
constraint 'r = 'r foo_t

class c : object('r)
  constraint 'r = 'r foo_t
  method get : 'r bar option
  method set : 'r bar option -> 'r
end
```

The concept here is, that class `c` can have elements of type `bar` which may in turn (somehow) reference to class `c`'s *complete* representation. So by inheriting from class `c`, the concrete type for `'r` gets updated with the complete class we have constructed.

The problem is: This interface crashes the typechecker. And I don't see why:

```
choeger@daishi /tmp % ocamlc -v                                   
The OCaml compiler, version 4.00.1
Standard library directory: /usr/lib64/ocaml
choeger@daishi /tmp % ocamlc -c -annot -o test.cmi test.mli 
Fatal error: exception Assert_failure("typing/ctype.ml", 246, 27)
```

So any hints on why this is problematic, or how this bahaves with different versions of OCaml are very much appreciated.

Comment: cool, indeed any failed assertion in ocaml compiler is a bug and should be reported. But do not forget to search a bugtracker, before you report

Comment: Bug is reported. Would be even cooler, if it was an error on my part ;).

Comment: Ticket - http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6496

Comment: @choeger, notwithstanding whether or not your code is buggy, failed assertion indicates that something impossible has happened. I've seen a similar error in ocaml 4.00, though it wasn't exactly that. It was fixed in a next release.

Answer (score 0):

```
ocaml
    OCaml version 4.02.3

# type 'r foo_t = <get : 'r bar option ; set : 'r bar option -> 'r; ..> as 'r 
  and 'r bar constraint 'r = 'r foo_t;;

Error: The definition of bar contains a cycle:
   'a foo_t as 'a
```

Looks like the assertion failure was fixed.